# How to instantiate an object in a new class?

Tags: python, class, oop, object

A bit of an odd question, but I'm wondering how to import an object from one class to another. I imagine adding more class methods and attributes as I expand my program, and I still want to be able to use old data. I am thinking something as follows:

```
class old_obj:

    def __init__(self, text):
        self.name = text

    def set_amount(self, num):
        self.amount = num

    def introduce_yourself(self):
        print("I am {} and I am {} many".format(self.name, self.amount))

oldest = old_obj("myself")
oldest.set_amount(15)
also_old = old_obj("Bach")

class new_obj:
    def __init__(self):
        #some code
    #more code
```

I want to be able to write something like:

```
renewed = new_obj(oldest)
also_new = new_obj(also_old)
```

Here, I want to retain the `15` from `oldest.amount`, but not complain that `also_old.amount` is `None`. In particular, I want to retain any attributes that `oldest` has, while not requiring that it have all possible attributes. Is there a way for me to copy over instances of a class to a new class?

**Edit**: edited for clarity

Comment: Why not extending it? `class new_obj(old_obj):`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly different take:

Your new class has a set of concerns that are probably similar to your old class. This should guide the way you update it and build out the behavior in question. With this in mind...

1. Provide a class method in your new class to allow construction of the new object from the old object. Don’t make this behavior a part of `__init__`. Your `__init__` should have a more limited responsibility. For the class method, updating the new object’s `__dict__` using the old object’s `__dict__` would do the job.
2. Don’t use inheritance to make new versions of classes. Use inheritance to move from general to specific or abstract to concrete. Otherwise, you end up with code that is hard to understand and update. (Imagine several generations down of just sub-classing in order to add some new methods.)
3. If the number of methods and attributes is growing, you might want to consider whether or not you’re encapsulating data/behaviors that should be split into multiple classes. The guiding principle is that you should encapsulate the data/behaviors that are likely to change together. That is, when you change the way you’re implementing your program, things that don’t need to change should probably be encapsulated separate from things that need changing. If you find that a lot of your static data is bound up with an object class that you’re frequently updating (but wanting to just import the old data unchanged), then you’ve probably got two different sets of concerns, at least.

Answer (score 2):

You could copy the object instance dict to the new class.

```
from copy import deepcopy

class old_obj:

    def __init__(self, text):
        self.name = text

    def set_amount(self, num):
        self.amount = num

    def introduce_yourself(self):
        print("I am {} and I am {} many".format(self.name, self.amount))

oldest = old_obj("myself")

class new_obj:
    def __init__(self, my_old_obj):
        for var, val in my_old_obj.__dict__.items():
            setattr(self, var, deepcopy(val))
        #some code
    #more code

newest = new_obj(oldest)
```

I did a deepcopy of the value assuming you want unique values in the new object. But that can also be problematic because not everything can be copied (file objects for instance). There can be other oddities when duplicating attributes such as what you want to do with a generator. And if this is something like a GUI widget, it could get stranger still.

But for a lot of object types, this would work.

Comment: This looks much more like what I'm looking for. I guess if I combine this with the answer from @Błotosmętek I can set new objects by either passing in an old one, or by passing in a string. I think this solves my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply initialize the new object by passing it the old one.

```
class old_obj:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

oldest = old_obj("myself")

class new_obj:
    def __init__(self, old_inst):
        self.text = old_inst.text 

renewed = new_obj(oldest)

print(renewed.text)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I was clear and specific enough, but I need in particular to be able to scale the instantiation based on how many attributed the original object has. I'm gonna edit my original question to make this clearer.

Comment: @Mathchiller - This scales... with a bit of typing.

Comment: The point is, I want to be able to plug in old objects, some of which have all their attributes set, and some which don't. I'd like to retain all the info they have, while simultaneously not requiring it.

Answer (score 1):

First, make your `new_obj` class inherit from `old_obj`, so that `new_obj` has all the methods `old_obj` had:

```
class new_obj(olb_obj):
```

Then, in `__init__` method of the new class you can check what is passed as the argument - a string or an object:

```
    def __init__(self, arg):
        if isinstance(arg, str):
            self.text = arg
        elif isinstance(arg, old_obj):
            self.text = arg.text 
        else:
            raise TypeError
```